# CSS height percentage specification

Tags: css

I'm trying to set out a screen-fitting application to my website, but I am having some problems, I know the ins and outs of CSS on the basics side, but I get a little confused when using percentages.

I need a header (50px), then I need a box (height 100%) then a small box footer(20px), but this all needs to be on the screen without overflow, when I try this with the given code I get an overflow because of the 100% item which pushes the footer down causing an overflow scrollbar.

```
<div id="holder"> <-- this is set to 100% width & height as well as html, body

     <div id="header">

     </div>

           <div id="inner_holder"> <-- This is the holder which is 100%

           </div>

    <div id="footer">

    <div/>

</div>
```

Comment: sounds like you need to Google css + sticky footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS `position` property to position the footer at the bottom. So, the remaining space is automatically available for your `inner_holder` div element.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>SO</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

div#holder {
    height: 100%;
    background: lightblue;
}

div#header {
    height: 50px;
    background: #800000;
}

div#inner_holder {
    background: lightblue;
}

div#footer {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #800000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="holder">

    <div id="header">
    Header
    </div>

    <div id="inner_holder">
    Inner holder
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
    Footer
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My advise is not to attempt making the `inner_holder` any fixed height at all. Position the header as normal with fixed height. Absolutely position the footer using `left` and `bottom` positions of 0 with a fixed height. Let the content flow normally with no modification. If scrollbars are needed the browser will accommodate. If you require background colors or images simply apply them to the `body`.